# Google Tag Manager strange requests

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We were loading Google Analytics via GTM but I removed it in our testing account, but I noticed now that it seems to do some weird requests still to:

```
www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js (this I recognise as normal)
www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js (Content-type: application/javascript)
```

What the heck is the last one? Is it normal? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

From the source of the file I figured out it is Google Optimize.